# Fusion Table Map Not Displaying Layers Properly

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to dynamically render a FusionTable map in the browser with a drop down menu that changes the map layer (and thus represented locations) based on the user selection.

Ive been scouring the net and the tutorials and thus far I've set up three tables and used the FusionTablesLayer Wizard to successfully create a single layered Map. So I've created an html document that allows me to display Layer 1 when the page loads. I would like to be able to swap that layer/table to correspond with the drop down menu selection.

At this point I can get the map/dropdown menu to load but when I select another layer from the menu I just get a permanant "data may still be loading" tiled message for each of my alternate layer selections.

I'm pretty new to both fusion tables and javascript. I'm sure that there is a simple error I am unaware of. If you'll please point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

I'll attach my code as it's been written thus far.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Layered Map</title>
<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
#map-canvas { width:1250px; height:600px; }
.layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
var tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ';
var locationColumn = 'Lat/Long';

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 265),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId
      },
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('option'),
        'change', function() {
          updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn);
    });
  }

  function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {
  var option = document.getElementById('option').value;
  if (option) {
  switch(option){
  case 2: layer = '1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w';
          break;
  case 3: layer = '1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0';
          break;
  default:
  case 1: layer = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ'; // first tableId
           break;
  }
  layer.setOptions({
      query: {
         select: locationColumn,
         from: tableId,
       }
  });
  } else {
  layer.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: locationColumn,
      from: tableId
    }
  });
  }
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



  </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <label>Layer</label>
  <select id="option">
  <option selected>--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no column "option" in your table:

```
function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {
  var option = document.getElementById('option').value;
  if (option) {
             layer.setOptions({
             query: {
                select: locationColumn,
                from: tableId,
          where: "option = '" + option + "'"
        }
      });
  } else {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Perhaps the "where" should be "'ID'="+option+"'"?  That would prevent the "Data may still be loading" message.  But from your question, it sounds like you want to change the *tableId* of the table, not the query.

[example using the column "ID" rather than "option"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_DataStillLoadingB.html)

If you want to update the map with a different *tableId* this may work, but you need to provide the three tableIds:

```
function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {
  var option = document.getElementById('option').value;
  if (option) {
    switch(option){
      case "2": tableId = '1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w';
                break;
      case "3": tableId = '1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0';
                break;
      default:
      case "1": tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ'; // first tableId
                break;
    }
    layer.setOptions({
          query: {
             select: locationColumn,
             from: tableId,
           },
           map: map
    });
  } else {
    layer.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

[working example with different table ids](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_DataStillLoadingC.html)

Comment: I see what you've done, thank you. I think you are correct, I am interested in swapping out for a new set of data locations altogether.       

The three tables are:
1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ (which what populates initially upon load. is there a way to load a blank map initially?)
1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w
1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0

I appreciate your quick response and assistance.

Comment: That table: 1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ is the same table in your original code.  To fix the problem you need to change your update map function, see my updated answer.

Comment: I've entered the other two viable alternate ids for case 2 and case 3, but it doesn't swap when I make the menu selections?

Comment: Oops, couldn't test the code as you didn't provide the tableIds.  There was a typo ('layer' should have been 'tableId') in the code, which is now fixed.

Comment: layer 2: 1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w
layer 3: 1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0

I'll edit my code in my question as well.

Comment: If you want no FusionTablesLayers to display when you map initially loads, remove the `map: map` from the constructor in your initialize function.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your patience. After editing layers for tableId and entering each FusionTable Id, I'm afraid it still remains inactive after menu selection.